# How to calculate percentage difference between two data frames with Pandas and return column and row names?

Tags: python, pandas, compare, datediff

I use pandas

For example, i have 2 df with same names of columns and rows

```
df1
    name    a   b
0   row1    3   2
1   row2    7   2
2   row3    1   6
```

```
df2
    name    a   b
0   row1    4   2
1   row2    7   2
2   row3    2   3
```

I need to calculate percetage difference, compare 2 df and return answer in this format **if the difference more then 30%** (no important is this increase or decrease):

"row2": "a"  increase by 33,3 %
"row 3" : "a"  increase by 50 %, "b" decrease by 50%

Answer (score 0):

Define `name` column as index of both dataframes then merge them:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('name').stack()
df2 = df2.set_index('name').stack()

out = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['l', 'r'],axis=1) \
        .pct_change(axis=1).mul(100) \
        .query('r.abs() >= 30')['r']
```

Output:

```
>>> out
out = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['l', 'r'],axis=1) \
        .pct_change(axis=1).mul(100) \
        .query('r.abs() >= 30')['r']
```

Output:

```
>>> out
name   
row1  a     33.333333
row3  a    100.000000
      b    -50.000000
Name: r, dtype: float64
```

With formatting:

```
lst = list(out.index.get_level_values(0) + ': '
           + out.index.get_level_values(1)
           + np.where(out > 0, ' increase by ', ' decrease by ')
           + out.map(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}%"))
print(lst)

# Output
['row1: a increase by 33.33%',
 'row3: a increase by 100.00%',
 'row3: b decrease by -50.00%']
```